# Переменные типа String в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Допустим, есть переменная Name : String; в нее уже помещено значение, заведомо не известное, как добавить в эту переменную еще слово, например, через пробел?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if IsWhiteSpace(Name[Length(Name)]) then 
  Name := Name + ' ';
Name := Name + 'трэш и угар, например';
```

Поскольку вопрос больше похож на тонкий намёк, оставляю реализацию `function IsWhiteSpace(C: Char): Boolean` на усмотрение читателя.

Answer (score 2):

пример конкатенации:

```
String:= String + ' ' + 'текст';
```

Работа со строками [ТУТ](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/work-with-strings.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
str := str + ' еще текст';
```